# replace words in filename BASH complications in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, sed

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095514/remove-a-list-of-words-from-filename) to my question which uses the following code to remove words from file names using `sed`:

```
for fyle in $(find . -name "*.*")
do 
  mv -i $fyle `echo $fyle | sed -e 's/FOO//gI' -e 's/BANG//gI' `
done
```

But on my mac it chokes on filenames whose paths have spaces.

I tried to fix it by use of double quotes, but couldn't get it to work: the variable fyle now includes the entire list of files, not one at a time.

Because the original poster seemed happy with the code, maybe my problem is because of my OSX flavour of bash?

How can I modify the code above to work well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, [quotes are your friends.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9712555/1072112)

But since you're using bash, you don't *really* need to use sed just to remove strings from filenames.  Something like this might work, using parameter expansion:

```
find . -name '*.*' -exec bash -c 'out="${1//FOO/}; out="${out//BANG/}; mv -v "$1" "$out"' -- {} \;
```

But even `find` is unnecessary in this case, so you can avoid subshells entirely:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*FOO*.* **/*BANG*.*; do
  out=${f//FOO/}
  out=${out//BANG/}
  mv -v "$f" "$out"
done
```

This of course assumes that the keywords you're searching for are before a dot in the filename. It also assumes that you're running bash v4, for `globstar`.

Comment: Ah, thanks muchly. :-) A combo of copy-paste and too-much-PHP-today I think.

Comment: Unfortunately the BASH in Mac OSX gives me an error on the first line.  I suspect it is because the BASH shipped with OSX is version 3.

Comment: Is there any way I can modify my original code to produce a solution, without depending on globstar?

Comment: @Tim, Right, I should have mentioned that earlier. Added the bash 4 dependency to the answer. As for how else to do this .. well, globstar is the only native bash way I know to recurse through directories the way `find` does. You have many choices -- find, bash4+globstar via [macports](https://www.macports.org/)/[brew](http://brew.sh/)/etc, PHP's [RecursiveDirectoryIterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) (since PHP 5 is included in OSX), Python's [os.walk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2212698/1072112) (since Python is also included). Pick your poison. :)

Comment: It's not too difficult to write a recursive shell function to do recursive directory descent in `bash` 3, but it's probably easier to simply install `bash` 4 via something like Homebrew.

Comment: yep, love globstar now.  also see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343727/filenames-with-spaces-breaking-for-loop-find-command) for why my original approach cannot be fixed. and they suggested the same approach as @anubhava.

Answer (score 4):

You should not iterate the `find` command's output in `for` loop otherwise shell expansion for filenames with space/newline will occur and your results will be wrong.

Use `-print0` option in `find` and iterate using **process substitution** in a `while read` loop with null `IFS`.

```
while IFS= read -rd '' fyle; do
   mv -i "$fyle" $(sed 's/FOO//gI; s/BANG//gI' <<< "$fyle")
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.*")
```

Comment: This works well, i preferred the answer of @ghoti because of simplicity; i am a newbie.

Comment: hold that comment, i just noticed that even though I didn't get an error, the file names have all remained unchanged.  So it didn't work!  Any ideas?

Comment: Insert a `declare -p fyle;` line before `mv` line and tell me what it prints.

Comment: it prints nothing!  but don't bother with this anymore, I've discovered the problem [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343727/filenames-with-spaces-breaking-for-loop-find-command) and I'm using the globstar approach.

Comment: Strange so you mean that `find` is not finding those files but `globstar` is able to find them?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to double-quote the variable reference in the `mv` command to account for the spaces...

```
mv -i "$fyle" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems very complicated. Will this work? Uses Bash's built-in string substitution and file globbing to replace `bar` with `baz`:

```
for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "${i/bar/baz}"; done
```

Here it is in action:

```
mike ~/foobar $ touch "foo bar baz.txt"
mike ~/foobar $ touch "foobar.txt"
mike ~/foobar $ touch "carbar.txt"
mike ~/foobar $ for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "${i/bar/baz}"; done
mike ~/foobar $ ls
carbaz.txt      foo baz baz.txt foobaz.txt
mike ~/foobar $
```

As chepner mentioned below, this will not recurse into directories.

Comment: Too simple; you aren't replicating the full behavior of `find`, and there is more than one substitution to make in the file name.

Comment: `find . -name "*.*"` isn't very complicated! Though I guess there is no recursion...